# Put in a dynamically created webpage the content of a HTML template file

Tags: php, templates, html

I have a HTML page that creates dynamically other HTML pages using PHP (fopen,fwrite,...).

The thing is that when I put the content of the HTML template I want for the page into a PHP variable I get into trouble because of the HTML characters (<,>, ...).

How can I avoid this ?
Can I import directly the content of the template file ?

Comment: What is the trouble you're getting exactly, are your < being replaced by &lt; for example ?

Comment: @Whiskas Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\site_artisans\site_artisan_index.php on line 473

Comment: showing the code (even pseudo-) that causes an error is always a good idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$content = file_get_contents("your_file.html");
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to include HTML files? That does not work but you could use readfile() instead. If you want to load the file into a variable, use file_get_contents().

Answer (score 0):

You can read contents from html file to string `$s` , handle with `$s` using php and next echo this: `echo $s`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close off php-tags like so:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <?php
        echo "It is now ".date("H:i");
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Only the code between  will be interpreted by the php interpreter.